rpm -qa but filtering for partial package name match?
I'm learning about the rpm package manager command. I figured out how to use rpm -qa however the list exceeds the overflow of the SSH program so I can't see the entire list.
How do I use the rpm command to list only packages that match a term? In example: "potato".

You can add a specifier to -a:
rpm -qa '*potato*'

This will only list packages with names containing “potato”.
Note that when you have too much output from a command, you can pipe it to less and scroll around it:
rpm -qa | less


And of course, you can rpm -q potato

@msuchy that only works with full package names though — but now that you mention it I see the question can be understood both ways.
